# How can I measure the flow rate of CO2 gas from two different canisters?

Tags: gas, experimental-physics, flow-control

I am looking for some help regarding one topic. I am designing one soda maker and thinking to include a 12g CO2 canister into it as my design only allows that size to incorporate . Now I know including a 14gm canister would be much better(more carbonation) but I am not sure how big the difference can be? So i am planning to do a flow testing to measure how much these two canister differ in case of co2 loading. But I am not sure how to design the testing method. Does anyone have any ideas or any references for a flow measuring test of gases? I will really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically you would use absorbent like Ca(OH)2 and weight it, to measure how much CO2 you got, through a CO2 permeable membrane to avoid H2O. But in your case its much simpler to just weight the canister before and after.

That is, you put a canister on a scale, write down the result, use the canister till its empty, put it on a scale again, write down the new result and subtract it from the first result. Difference is mass is likely mostly due to escaped CO2. May also account for that tiny seal mass, if it gets ripped off while opening.